# Parallel.For with BigInteger calculations output different than For loop

Tags: c#, biginteger, parallel.for

I have the following loop that runs a conversion from base95 to base10. I'm working with several thousand digit numbers, so BigIntegers are required. `inst` is the base95 string.

```
Parallel.For(0, inst.Length, x => 
     {
        result += BigInteger.Pow(95, x) * (inst[x] - 32);
     });
```

If I work with base95 strings of about 200 characters or less, it works perfectly fine and outputs the same result that a normal `for` loop would.

However, once I start increasing the size of the base95 string, the parallel's output is thrown way off. I need to work with base95 strings with 1500+ characters, and even up to 30000. A regular `for` loop can calculate the result fine.

What could be causing this problem? Is there a better method to this than a `Parallel.For` loop that's still faster than a `for` loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its just not thread safe. As to why its not corrupting with smaller strings, i'm not sure. Possibly *TPL* just doesn't think the workload is worthy of extra threads. Though, i did verified your results, it does produce inconsistent results with larger strings.

The only solution will be to make it thread safe. A cheap and nasty approach will be to use `lock`... It would be better if you could user another thread safe approach like [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), however, it wont work with `BigInteger`.

```
BigInteger result = 0;
object sync = new object();

Parallel.For(
   0,
   inst.Length,
   x =>
      {
         var temp = BigInteger.Pow(95, x) * (inst[x] - 32);
         lock (sync)
            result += temp;
      });
```

Its not perfect with all the locking but its still faster than a regular `for` loop on my pc

Another approach would be to use the for overloads, this way you are only locking once per each thread.

```
Parallel.For(
   0,
   inst.Length,
   () => new BigInteger(0),
   (x, state, subTotal) => subTotal + BigInteger.Pow(95, x) * (inst[x] - 32),
   integer =>
      {
         lock (sync)
            result += integer;
      });
```

---

## Benchmarks

So i was bored, here is your bench marks

Tests were run 50 times each, `GC.Collect` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` is run before every test to give cleaner results. All results were tested against each other to prove they are accurate. `Scale` represents the size of the string as per your question

**Setup**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9
Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3901 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Results**

```
--- Random characters -----------------------------------------------------------------
| Value          |    Average |    Fastest |    Cycles | Garbage | Test |        Gain |
--- Scale 10 ----------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.259 ---
| for            |   5.442 µs |   4.968 µs |  21.794 K | 0.000 B | Base |      0.00 % |
| ParallelResult |  32.451 µs |  30.397 µs | 116.808 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   -496.25 % |
| ParallelLock   |  35.551 µs |  32.443 µs | 127.966 K | 0.000 B | Pass |   -553.22 % |
| AsParallel     | 141.457 µs | 118.959 µs | 398.676 K | 0.000 B | Pass | -2,499.13 % |
--- Scale 100 ---------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.298 ---
| ParallelResult |  93.261 µs |  80.085 µs | 329.450 K | 0.000 B | Pass |     11.36 % |
| ParallelLock   | 103.912 µs |  84.470 µs | 366.599 K | 0.000 B | Pass |      1.23 % |
| for            | 105.210 µs |  93.823 µs | 371.025 K | 0.000 B | Base |      0.00 % |
| AsParallel     | 183.538 µs | 159.002 µs | 488.534 K | 0.000 B | Pass |    -74.45 % |
--- Scale 1,000 -------------------------------------------------------- Time 4.191 ---
| AsParallel     |   5.701 ms |   4.932 ms |  15.479 M | 0.000 B | Pass |     65.83 % |
| ParallelResult |   6.510 ms |   5.701 ms |  18.166 M | 0.000 B | Pass |     60.98 % |
| ParallelLock   |   6.734 ms |   5.303 ms |  17.314 M | 0.000 B | Pass |     59.64 % |
| for            |  16.685 ms |  15.640 ms |  58.183 M | 0.000 B | Base |      0.00 % |
--- Scale 10,000 ------------------------------------------------------ Time 34.805 ---
| AsParallel     |    6.205 s |    4.767 s |  19.202 B | 0.000 B | Pass |     47.20 % |
| ParallelResult |    6.286 s |    5.891 s |  14.752 B | 0.000 B | Pass |     46.51 % |
| ParallelLock   |    6.290 s |    5.202 s |   9.982 B | 0.000 B | Pass |     46.48 % |
| for            |   11.752 s |   11.436 s |  41.136 B | 0.000 B | Base |      0.00 % |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ParallelLock**

```
[Test("ParallelLock", "", true)]
public BigInteger Test1(string input, int scale)
{
   BigInteger result = 0;
   object sync = new object();

   Parallel.For(
      0,
      input.Length,
      x =>
         {
            var temp = BigInteger.Pow(95, x) * (input[x] - 32);
            lock (sync)
               result += temp;
         });

   return result;
}
```

**ParallelResult**

```
[Test("ParallelResult", "", false)]
public BigInteger Test2(string input, int scale)
{
   BigInteger result = 0;
   object sync = new object();
   Parallel.For(
      0,
      input.Length,
      () => new BigInteger(0),
      (x, state, subTotal) => subTotal + BigInteger.Pow(95, x) * (input[x] - 32),
      integer =>
         {
            lock (sync)
               result += integer;
         });
   return result;
}
```

**AsParallel** as tendered by [gdir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3563563/gdir)

```
[Test("AsParallel", "", false)]
public BigInteger Test4(string input, int scale)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length)
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Aggregate(
                        new BigInteger(0),
                        (subtotal, x) => subtotal + BigInteger.Pow(95, x) * (input[x] - 32),
                        (total, thisThread) => total + thisThread,
                        (finalSum) => finalSum);;
}
```

**for**

```
[Test("for", "", false)]
public BigInteger Test3(string input, int scale)
{       
   BigInteger result = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
   {
      result += BigInteger.Pow(95, i) * (input[i] - 32);
   }
   return result;
}
```

**Input**

```
public static string StringOfChar(int scale)
{
   var list = Enumerable.Range(1, scale)
                        .Select(x => (char)(_rand.Next(32)+32))
                        .ToArray();
   return string.Join("", list);
}
```

**Validation**

```
private static bool Validation(BigInteger result, BigInteger baseLine)
{
   return result == baseLine;
}
```

## Summary

Parallel will give you a performance boost, the less you can lock the better it is in theory, however there maybe many factors of why the results played out the way they did. its seems the result overload seems to work well, but is pretty similar with the larger workloads, i'm not really sure why. Note i didn't play with the parallel options, and you might be able to tweak it a little bit  more for your solution

anyway, good luck

Comment: Excellent answer. Would you mind to add a benchmark for LINQ AsParallel with Aggregate?

Comment: @gdir updated, ill do a more thorough test though over the next hour. it does perform well though and a very neat solution

Comment: I ran a test myself using the ParallelResult method and ~31k characters. Not only was it 6 minutes faster, but it also output the correct result. Thank you! Marked as the answer.